# National flight with expired tourist visa

Tags: visas, ecuador

I am a Spanish citizen, and I am currently traveling in Ecuador. My three month tourist visa has already expired. Nonetheless, I can travel freely inside Ecuador by bus. If the police ask me for my passport in the street, they cannot force me to leave the country. When I leave the country, I will have to pay a $200 fine, that's all. I only need to pay this fine if I intend to come back to Ecuador within two years.

My question is, can take a national flight from Quito to Galapagos (which belongs to Ecuador), with my expired tourist visa.

If I understand it correctly, national flights, even for tourists, do not require a valid passport, nor a valid tourist visa. Is that true?

Also, it seems that even if Galapagos belongs to Ecuador, they have special rules other from the national flights.

Comment: Generally speaking, we do not provide suggestions how to break laws on this board, or advise people to do so. You should either get a visa extension or return home as required by law.

Comment: @o.m. Technically speaking his law-breaking isn't germane to the question.  That he chooses to do so would rightfully be considered distasteful by most people, but that is his business.  If the OP had simply asked if he needed to show his passport for a flight from Quito to Galapagos, then no-one would know or care about his immigration status.